# Why an unsaved modified NSManagedObject returns FALSE on isUpdated after closing/opening app?

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Why an unsaved but modified NSManagedObject has an empty -changedValues and returns FALSE on - isUpdated after closing/opening the app (running in background)?

I don't want to save a modified `NSManagedObject` on `applicationDidEnterBackground`, but I want to know whether it was updated after `applicationWillEnterForeground`.

In my implementation I get an **empty** `[object changedValues]` and **FALSE** `[object isUpdated]`

Is this normal? What could I do to not save an modified object, quit app, return and get the `isUpdated` **TRUE**?

Answer (score 0):

In `applicationDidEnterBackground` simply check `isUpdated` and set a variable to the result. In `applicationWillEnterForeground` check your variable.

However, I do not think that is good practice. Why would you not want to save on entering background? Either you want to persist the change, then save it; or you don't, then throw it out.

Remember, once the app is in the background, there is no guarantee it will ever come back. So the rule is that you should persist everything you need in order to recreate it when the app becomes active again.

Comment: I think this wouldn't be a good practice either and I understand the saving process as you explained. The thing is, I would like to have this property working right so I could use it to warn the user when he tries to create a new "object", just like you close an unsaved document and the app asks you to save the modified doc. But I guess the easiest way is creating a new property for storing a "changed content" bool.
Thanks for your answer!